# Is it possible to get "importing module" in "imported module" in Python?

Tags: python

For imported module, is it possible to get the importing module (name)? I'm wondering if **inspect** can achieve it or not~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**foo.py**:

import bar

---

**bar.py**:

```
import traceback
try:
    filename,line_number,function_name,text = traceback.extract_stack()[-2]
    print(filename,line_number,function_name,text)
except IndexError:
    pass
```

---

Running foo.py yields something like

```
('/home/unutbu/pybin/foo.py', 4, '<module>', 'import bar')
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you solved your own problem: use the `inspect` module.  I'd traverse up the stack until I found a frame where the current function was not `__import__`.  But I bet if you told people why you want to do this, they'd tell you not to.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you got it to work, this is probably less useful than you think since subsequent imports only copy the existing reference instead of executing the module again.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, but is important information.

Comment: @Karl: Although it could be seen as a comment, it goes far in answering the question with "no".

Comment: Curious to know the reason behind 'not suggest to do this'. What I want to do is to provide a function **deprecatedModule(new_module)** used in deprecated modules.

Comment: @Drake: It's not that I suggest you don't do this, it's that the module will only be imported proper once per application execution. Also, [`DeprecationWarning`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.DeprecationWarning).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Didn't know this DeprecationWarning, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import inspect
result = filter(lambda v:inspect.ismodule(v), globals().values())
#result is a collection of all imported modules in the file, the name of any of which can be easily got by .__name__
#replace globals() with inspect.getmembers(wanted_module) if you want the result outside the wanted module
```